# How to replace string to the other string in list (python)

Tags: python

What is the best way to replace every string in the list?

For example if I have a list:

```
a = ['123.txt', '1234.txt', '654.txt']
```

and I would like to have:

```
a = ['123', '1234', '654']
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you are having trouble with modifying strings or with doing it repeatedly to create a `list`. Technically, "just do `a = ['123', '1234', '654']`" would be an accurate way to answer this as it stands. You are making answerers engage in "psychic debugging" (a.k.a. "guessing").

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that sample input is similar to what you actually have, use `os.path.splitext()` to remove file extensions:

```
>>> import os
>>> a = ['123.txt', '1234.txt', '654.txt']
>>> [os.path.splitext(item)[0] for item in a]
['123', '1234', '654']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension as follows:

```
a = ['123.txt', '1234.txt', '654.txt']
answer = [item.replace('.txt', '') for item in a]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['123', '1234', '654']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all your strings end with '.txt', just slice the last four characters off.

```
>>> a = ['123.txt', '1234.txt', '654.txt']
>>> a = [x[:-4] for x in a]
>>> a
['123', '1234', '654']
```

This will also work if you have some weird names like 'some.txtfile.txt'

Comment: @user3612491 No problem. As a hint, I think you could have asked that question a little clearer. For example, if you want to replace any string, my answer does not apply. It is also unclear what should happen with filenames I have mentioned such as 'some.txtfile.txt'. At some point we would have to use regular expressions, but your problem seems to be more specific while the title of the question is very broad.

Answer (score 1):

You could split you with `.` separator and get first item:

```
In [486]: [x.split('.')[0] for x in a]
Out[486]: ['123', '1234', '654']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
a = [x[: -len("txt")-1] for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to replace every string in the list?

That completely depends on how you define 'best'. I, for example, like regular expressions:

```
import re
a = ['123.txt', '1234.txt', '654.txt']
answer = [re.sub('^(\w+)\..*', '\g<1>', item) for item in a]
#print(answer)
#['123', '1234', '654']
```

Depending on the content of the strings, you could adjust it:

- `\w+` vs `[0-9]+` for only digits
- `\..*` vs `\.txt` if all strings end with .txt

Answer (score 0):

```
data.colname = [item.replace('anythingtoreplace', 'desiredoutput') for item in data.colname]
```

> Please note here 'data' is the dataframe, 'colname' is the column name you might have in that dataframe. Even the spaces are accounted, if you want to remove them from a string or number. This was quite useful for me. Also this does not change the datatype of the column so you might have to do that separately if required.